# Any examples of arrays in c#?

Tags: c#

can i get any examples on arrays, i want to practice the arrays examples, is there any reference site for arrays to practice. In most interviews they are asking array examples

Comment: Tried googling it? duh..
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: In interviews, they probably want you to show that you know it's not called "C# dot net". Probably want you to prove you know where the online documentation is, as well. Better hope they don't find this question when they google for your name.

Comment: http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/basics/arrays/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the documentation and tutorials, you can look into short http://www.youtube.com videos to explain array concepts and show examples.  Here is one example : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJLDsP7bE-4

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN's article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(VS.71).aspx)  would be the best start on arrays and also [c# arraylist samples](http://dotnetperls.com/arraylist)